# Proofs about infinite numbers of primes of different forms

Tags: analysis

I am not an expert of primes numbers. But I noticed the following. It is known that there are infinitely many primes that have a linear form-this is implied from Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progression or the Green-Tao theorem. But when primes are of an exponential form (i.e. it involves an positive integer raised to the power of another positive) such as Mersenne Primes, double Mersenne Primes or Fermat Primes then it is not known if there are such infinite primes. Which leads to my question, why is it more difficult to prove there are infinite primes of that have a form involving some given exponential term as compared to proving if there are infinite primes of a given linear form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (big) issue is that, in passing to higher degrees, you forfeit a tremendously powerful tool, namely the divergence of the reciprocal sum.  Thus, Dirichlet is able to show there are infinitely many primes of the form $an+b$ (if $a,b$ are fixed and relatively prime) by showing that $$\sum_{p=an+b}\frac 1p$$ diverges. (where, of course, the sum is taken over the primes in the given progression).

That powerful tool is lost, even for simple (sounding) questions like "primes of the form $n^2+1$".  Indeed, $\sum\frac 1{n^2+1}$ converges so we surely have $$\sum_{p=n^2+1}\frac 1p<\infty$$